# Python - Choose Min Date with Max Value by ID

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to keep only the rows, grouping by ID with first finding the min date and then from the rows with the min date filtering it more to only the max value by ID. There may be null values which should be ignored.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[111, 111, 111, 112, 112],
                   'Value':[10, 98, 99, 65, None],
                   'Date': ['1/1/2016', '1/1/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/6/2018', '1/7/2018']})
```

Input

```
ID   Value     Date
111  10        1/1/2016
111  98        1/1/2016
111  99        1/3/2016
112  65        1/6/2018
112  NULL      1/7/2018
```

Output

```
ID   Value     Date
111  98        1/1/2016
112  65        1/6/2018
```

I think I'm close but putting in the min date is confusing me a bit. I am using the following:

`df.groupby("ID").max())`

Answer (score 0):

Filter the min dates first, then get the indexes from your target-column with the maximum value:

```
df = df.loc[df[df.Date.isin(df.groupby('ID').Date.min())].groupby('ID').Value.idxmax()]
```

To groupby only once:

```
def func(grp):
    return grp.loc[grp[grp.Date==grp.Date.min()].Value.idxmax()]
df = df.groupby('ID').apply(func).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

Just to make sure your Date column is date, type `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`. Although I think you did that, it's needed for running the chunks above with your example.

Comment: Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
It changed my ID column to scientific notation.

Comment: When you do `df.groupby('ID').Date.min()` you'll not get missing labels.

Comment: I do receive a new error with the groupby once only code: TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [nan] of <class 'float'>

Comment: After QAing your code, it does not work. Not sure why that is the case. I did filter out the missing values as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There were a mistypo in my code (wrong column name). Please try it again to see if it works for you. It worked well for me with your example, even with missing values in the other columns. If it does not, we'll have to wait for some additional help =x

Comment: I tried again, and it is not showing the appropriate values or dates now.

Comment: It does for your example. What do you mean by "appropriate values"? What's wrong? Have you set the `Date` column to date type before running the code? Your `NULL` value is `NaN`?

Comment: See that, by default, your example is parsed as `%m/%d/%Y` in the `pd.to_datetime` function. If it's not the case for you, specify the appropriate format (e.g. `%d/%m/%Y`).